# PHP: Get last Tag of a String with Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex, tags

Quite simple problem (but difficult solution): I got a string in PHP like as follows:

```
['one']['two']['three']
```

And from this, i must extract the last tags, so i finally got `three`

it is also possible that there is a number, like

```
[1][2][3]
```

and then i must get `3`

How can i solve this?

Thanks for your help!

Flo

Comment: Can the string contain more than tags? E.g. `asdf['one']asdf['two']asdf['three']asdf`?

Comment: No, there is the last tag at the end, and except these tags, there is no text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tag is `\[[^\]]+\]`.

3 Tags are: `(\[[^\]]+\]){3}`

3 Tags at end are: `(\[[^\]]+\]){3}$`

N Tags at end are: `(\[[^\]]+\])*$` (N 0..n)

Example:

```
<?php
    $string = "['one']['two']['three'][1][2][3]['last']";
    preg_match("/((?:\[[^\]+]*\]){3})$/", $string, $match);
    print_r($match); // Array ( [0] => [2][3]['last'] [1] => [2][3]['last'] )
```

Comment: I don't get it ... I tried with ereg, but it did not work :S I tried as follows: `ereg("\[[^\]]+\]",$string)`, but it wont work. And another thing, all regex functions are marked as deprecated on php.net :S ...

Comment: Have an example as well as missing brackets added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that may work for you. Try this:

```
[^\[\]']*(?='?\]$)
```

Answer (score 1):

This tested code may work for you:

```php
function getLastTag($text) {
    $re = '/
        # Match contents of last [Tag].
        \[              # Literal start of last tag.
        (?:             # Group tag contents alternatives.
          \'([^\']+)\'  # Either $1: single quoted,
        | (\d+)         # or $2: un-quoted digits.
        )               # End group of tag contents alts.
        \]              # Literal end of last tag.
        \s*             # Allow trailing whitespace.
        $               # Anchor to end of string.
        /x';
    if (preg_match($re, $text, $matches)) {
        if ($matches[1]) return $matches[1]; // Either single quoted,
        if ($matches[2]) return $matches[2]; // or non quoted digit.
    }
    return null; // No match. Return NULL.
}
```